# Looking for a phpmyadmin tool who shows the tables in "design mode" with relations

Tags: phpmyadmin, schema

Ais in the title

One day I saw on phpmyadmin a tool capable of drawing a schema of the table in the database linked with primary keys / foreign keys together.

Where can I find this tools please? (what's its name?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/). There's also [SQLFairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/). They both do what you're looking for.

Comment: great. but .jar won't launch on my pc, i have Java Runtime installed + Java binary.... ='(

Answer (score 0):

The new phpmyadmin has designer, and it shows(I think) connections between tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a tutorial that shows you how to set up phpMyAdmins designer mode. You need to create a storage database. Click [here](http://havenofcode.com/tutorial.php?tut=9) to find out how!